# Storing found foreach values in PHP to Java

Tags: java, php, foreach

So, I'm really new to Java (signed up for a spring semester course on it matter of fact) and I'm trying out some basic Java exercises.

I'm attempting to make JAR plugins for a certain game whose server software is written in Java and there is a similar plugin written in PHP for the same game except that the server engine software is written in PHP not Java. The developer for the PHP plug-in provides his source code on a GitHub repo.

The current problem I'm having is (I've bought a 24 hour learn Java book and read through it already and done most of its activities but it didn't seem to cover this very well; and I've also thoroughly search wide and far over Google and other Stack questions and tutorials, etc. to no avail) trying to 'convert' these few lines to Java from the PHP plugin.

```
$c = $this->getConfig()->getAll();
foreach ($c["Commands"] as $i) {
$this->getServer()->getScheduler()->scheduleRepeatingTask(new 
TimeCommand($this,$i["Command"]),$i["Time"] * 1200);
```

I understand what the code is saying which is to get all data from the config file, and for each section labeled "Commands", store as `$i`, then `scheduleRepeatingTask` (`scheduleRepeatingTask(Task task, into period);` where task is a command to run is a variable to my understanding.) running every listed command in the config at the interval of the time specified in the config file. The data is coming from a LinkedHashMap, too.

```java
public class main extends PluginBase {
    public List<String> list;
    public Config config;
    public static String cmd;
    public LinkedHashMap LinkedHashMap;

    public void onEnable() {
        if (!this.getDataFolder().exists()) {
            this.getDataFolder().mkdirs();
            this.config = new Config(new File(this.getDataFolder() + "/config.yml"), 2, (LinkedHashMap)new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(){
                {
                    put("commands", new String[] { "command", "time" });
                }
            });

            config.save();
        }

        this.saveDefaultConfig();

        Object configData = this.getConfig().getAll();

        configData.forEach((configData["commands"]) -> {
            final Long cmds[] = new Long[1];
            cmds[0] = commands.getKey();
            this.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleRepeatingTask(null, null, 0);
        });
    }
```

I just can't seem for the life of me to get this to work for some reason, even after all the researching I've done on the forEach loops.

Sorry if this is a stupid question or anything, I'm just trying to learn (yes I clicked the related questions above and found nothing all that helpful; unless I'm blind which tends to happen a lot).

Comment: Can you update your question to include the Java code you wrote that's equivalent to the PHP code?

Comment: Yes, was thinking about that. Edit: done. Sorry if messy code or if it isn't being written in the most efficient way. I haven't gotten to that level of skill yet.